# Command grep failing in ansible when grep item not present

Tags: ansible

Here the following piece of code is waiting  for the kubernetest pod to be disappeared  after launch.
pod do disappeared but the script fails  with the error.
I want to wait till pod disappeared and the continue with rest of the task.

```
- name: Check ms pod has disappeared
  sudo: yes
  run_once: true
  when: ansible_hostname !=  "inception-{{ vms_subdomain }}"
  shell: "kubectl get pod --namespace=vms | grep {{ item.key }}"
  register: command_res
  with_dict: "{{ microservices }}"
  until: "command_res.rc == 1"
  retries: 10
  delay: 20

TASK [sp-sif : Check ms resouce has disappeared] *******************************
Tuesday 07 February 2017  15:26:52 +0000 (0:00:02.051)       0:03:23.889 ******
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: sp-sif : Check ms resouce has disappeared (5 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: sp-sif : Check ms resouce has disappeared (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: sp-sif : Check ms resouce has disappeared (3 retries left).

failed: [kubernetes-master-vik202vmsservices-1] (item={'key': u'iwan', 'value': {u'streams': u'ncs-alarms'}}) => {"attempts": 4, "changed": true, "cmd": "kubectl get pod --namespace=vms | grep iwanms", "del
ta": "0:00:00.048855", "end": "2017-02-07 15:28:26.707882", "failed": true, "item": {"key": "iwan", "value": {"streams": "ncs-alarmsf"}}, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-02-07 15:28:26.659027", "stderr": "", "stdout
": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Comment: This task is not optimal. Try to do it without loop, e.g. add `-o json` to `kubectl` and parse stdout as json to search for all keys at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should work with a failed_when instruction, example:

```
- name: Check ms pod has disappeared
  sudo: yes
  run_once: true
  #when: ansible_hostname !=  "inception-{{ vms_subdomain }}"
  shell: "cat /tmp/runbmct2.sh|grep raulhugo"
  register: command_res
  #with_dict: "{{ microservices }}"
  until: "command_res.rc == 1"
  failed_when: "'NOT' in command_res.stdout"
  retries: 10
  delay: 20
- name: Check the output
  debug: var=command_res
```

As you see in the example I added to your task **failed_when: "'NOT' in command_res.stdout"**  if you at this and run you playbook again it wont fail.

When you use this kind of command grep you should especify where it will fails.